# how to resolve install problem with tensorflow-model-analysis using jupyterlab notebook?

Tags: tensorflow-model-analysis

I am trying to follow the guide on this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis) but I get an error on the second step for enabling TFMA visualization in Jupyter Notebook.  I assume this is something you do in a cell?

Answer (score 1):

Those commands are mean to be run in the terminal.  Here is the process for anaconda.

1. Open a shell in the python2 environment.
2. Issue this command

> jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

3. Issue this command with the --sys-prefix option since you are using a virtual environment

> jupyter nbextension install --sys-prefix --py --symlink
>   tensorflow_model_analysis

4. Issue this command

> jupyter nbextension enable --py tensorflow_model_analysis